# KEYBOARD_DOM_ERROR

Tags: angular, dom, was

I'm trying to make a virtual keyboard in my angular app, And i found Simple-keyboard package so that i decided to install it and customize it but i get some error like **".simple-keyboard" was not found in the DOM.** what's the problem? Someone can help me?

**I'm using angular 11.2.8**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm using this package with Angular 8, not sure if this can help.

When I installed and followed the steps with [Angular example](https://hodgef.com/simple-keyboard/editor/?d=hodgef/angular-simple-keyboard/tree/master), I saw **KEYBOARD_DOM_ERROR** in my console either, then I found the solution for me which [this issue](https://github.com/hodgef/simple-keyboard/issues/57) answered.

> `KEYBOARD_DOM_ERROR` means that `<div class="simple-keyboard"></div>` was not found in the dom at instantiation.

And I tried to create an element in `.ts` file instead of just add in template, just like the issue said.

```js
// component.ts
// you can add other className to make keyboard display:none first

ngOnInit(): void {
  const div = document.createElement('div');
  div.className += "simple-keyboard";
  document.body.appendChild(div);
}
```

```
<!-- component.html -->
<!-- just want to remind you need to delete it -->

<!-- <div class="simple-keyboard"></div> -->
```

After these two things, my error disappear, and I can do what I need to do next.

Answer (score 1):

Add following code in your html file

```html
  <div class="simple-keyboard"></div>
```

Comment: Well there can be many possible issues. First check the compiled application in browser, and check if the div with .simple-keyboard is shown. If not, you need to make sure that your component is added into the main application or any component that should use it

Comment: I was getting this error because my `class="simple-keyboard"` `div` was inside a `*ngIf` `div`, that was set after the constructor.  My solution was to wrap the `new Keyboard` in `setTimeout`.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that your html has a div with the simple-keyboard class (or whatever name you gave to your keyboard).

If the error keeps happening try creating the instance of the keyboard after the view has been initialized:

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
  this.keyboard = new Keyboard(".simple-keyboard",{
    onChange: input => this.onChange(input),
    onKeyPress: button => this.onKeyPress(button)
  });
}
```